# Making jQuery code dynamic/shorter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written that simply show `div` on hover and for this the `jQuery` is following, I am trying to make it dynamic so the code remains in same line but getting error, can somebody please help?

```
$(".column-wrapper-main").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov1").css("opacity", "1"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov1").css("opacity", "0"); 
});

$(".column-wrapper-main2").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov2").css("opacity", "1"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov2").css("opacity", "0"); 
});
//Box 3
$(".column-wrapper-main3").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov3").css("opacity", "1"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov3").css("opacity", "0"); 
});

//Box 4
$(".column-wrapper-main4").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov4").css("opacity", "1"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov4").css("opacity", "0"); 
});
//Box 5
$(".column-wrapper-main5").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov5").css("opacity", "1"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov5").css("opacity", "0"); 
});
//Box 6
$(".column-wrapper-main6").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov6").css("opacity", "1"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov6").css("opacity", "0"); 
});
//Box 7
$(".column-wrapper-main7").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov7").css("opacity", "1"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov7").css("opacity", "0"); 
});
//Box 8
$(".column-wrapper-main8").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov8").css("opacity", "1"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov8").css("opacity", "0"); 
});
```

Comment: Where is the html?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not applying a class to all elements?

```
$('.column-effect').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(".column-wrapper-hov" + $(e.delegateTarget).attr('data-index')).css("opacity", e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 1 : 0); 
});
```

And assign a data attribute per element, like this:

```
<div class="column-wrapper-main column-effect" data-index="1"></div>
```

Reviewing this again, I wouldn't even use JavaScript for the job. Simple CSS would be enough:

```
.column-effect {
    opacity : 0;
}
    .column-effect:hover {
        opacity: 1
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All of them should use the same classes, without numbers. Than you simply refer to a selector within the given context. This only works if they are nested.

```
$(".column-wrapper-main").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov", $(this)).css("opacity", "1");
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".column-wrapper-hov",$(this)).css("opacity", "0");;
});
```

If they are not nested you could use data attribute to get the target id.

```
$(".column-wrapper-main").mouseenter(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).css("opacity", "1");
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).css("opacity", "0");
});
```

Comment: Assuming that `column-wrapper-hov` is contained inside `column-wrapper-main`.

Comment: Assuming the divs are nested, otherwise this won't work

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove `index` from `class` names and add `id` to it. And refactor your HTML something like this

```
<div class="column-wrapper-main" id="column-wrapper-main-1">
   <!-- Bla bla bla -->
</div>
<div class="column-wrapper-main" id="column-wrapper-main-2">
   <!-- Bla bla bla -->
</div>
```

Then in JS/jQuery you can traverse like

```
$('.column-wrapper-main').mouseenter(function () {
    var number = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[3];
    $(".column-wrapper-hov" + number).css("opacity", "1");
}).mouseleave(function () {
    var number = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[3];
    $(".column-wrapper-hov" + number).css("opacity", "0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of your HTML layout, so I was unable to extensively test this, but this may work for you.

```
$("[class^=column-wrapper-main]").mouseenter(function() {
  var letter = ($(this).attr('class'))
  var combined = ".column-wrapper-hov" + letter.substr(letter.length - 1);
  $(combined).css("opacity", "1"); 
  }).mouseleave(function() {
  var letter = ($(this).attr('class'))
  var combined = ".column-wrapper-hov" + letter.substr(letter.length - 1);
  $(combined).css("opacity", "0"); 
});
```